# How to Access a Variable that is Associated with other Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I need your Help Regarding an Issue that is Scratching my Head, Here I Got a Material Button, there is a Variable in it, that I want to Use in the Text Widget.

```
                   MaterialButton(
                         onPressed: () {
                          // My Random Code Goes Here. (Never Mind)

                           var currentEmoji = ...;
                         },
```

As you can see, I got a Material Button and Inside there is a big code, and the thing which I need to show you is the "currentEmoji" Variable.

I need to use this Variable in this Text Widget, which sits Just below this bit of Code,

```
                       child: Text(
                          *currentEmoji*,
                          textScaleFactor: 2,
                        ),
```

1. I have a Material Button
2. I have an On Pressed Function in it.
3. In that Function there is a Variable `currentEmoji`
4. I want to Display this Variable inside the Text Widget
5. How to use `currentEmoji` Variable Outside the onPressed Function.

I want to Seek Your Help at this.

Comment: You have already asked 3-4 question on same topic this material button. Without acknowledging any of the answer from any of the user.

Comment: Sir nope, The Material button is the same and I admit, but this is a different scenario, I seriously want to know how can we access `currentEmoji` outside the onPressed, and Earlier I haven't ever asked, #admitting that Material Buttons are used in every case. That's just a way to present a Question. I hope you understand. and help me seek the roots of this answer.  @ProblematicDude

Comment: Assuming that it's in the same class but in different function, just make a global variable for it. If it's in the same function (function that creates the widget), make a local variable scoped in that function. Sample: `void _buildWidget() { var emoji = 'default'; ... }`

Comment: @ProCo Just declare it's outside the onPressed method. Whats the big deal

Comment: @Shree I am with you on the edit, but please explain the reasons to OP. They might be trying to get out of a question ban by improving negative scored questions, a good idea. Help them actually improve this without invalidating answer (which I think is your reason....).

Answer (score 1):

See below code,

```
class MyHomeActivity extends StatelessWidget {
  // elements declared here can be used anywhere in this class
  var currentEmoji;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // use currentEmoji here
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

No offence, but this is the basic concept of declaring variable globally, the common programming concept.

I encourage you to please go through the official docs of dart language [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

This will definitely ease you development journey.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at it [in dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/b920c76e7c8be112acf4bdf07cdd30cb?null_safety=true):

You need to declare the variable outside these two widgets, like so:

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String _currentEmoji = 'my initial emoji';

  void _setEmoji() {
    // My Random Code Goes Here. (Never Mind)
    setState(() {
      _currentEmoji = 'new emoji';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: _setEmoji,
        child: Text('press me'),
      ),
      Text(_currentEmoji),
    ]);
  }
}
```